# Can you help me combining these sensor sketches as one in Arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors

I want to combine these three sketches into one.

RAIN SENSOR:

```
int rainPin = A0;
int greenLED = 6;
int redLED = 7;
// you can adjust the threshold value
int thresholdValue = 500;

void setup(){
  pinMode(rainPin, INPUT);
  pinMode(greenLED, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(redLED, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(greenLED, LOW);
  digitalWrite(redLED, LOW);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  // read the input on analog pin 0:
  int sensorValue = analogRead(rainPin);
  Serial.print(sensorValue);

  if(sensorValue < thresholdValue){
    Serial.println(" - It's wet");
    digitalWrite(greenLED, LOW);
    digitalWrite(redLED, HIGH);
  }
  else {
    Serial.println(" - It's dry");
    digitalWrite(greenLED, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(redLED, LOW);
  }
  delay(500);
}
```

LIGHT SENSOR:

```
int ldrPin = A0;
int greenLED = 6;
int redLED = 7;
// you can adjust the threshold value
int thresholdValue = 500;

void setup(){
  pinMode(ldrPin, INPUT);
  pinMode(greenLED, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(redLED, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(greenLED, LOW);
  digitalWrite(redLED, LOW);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  // read the input on analog pin 0:
  int sensorValue = analogRead(ldrPin);
  Serial.print(sensorValue);

  if(sensorValue < thresholdValue){
    Serial.println(" - light");
    digitalWrite(greenLED, LOW);
    digitalWrite(redLED, HIGH);
  }
  else {
    Serial.println(" - dark");
    digitalWrite(greenLED, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(redLED, LOW);
  }
  delay(500);
}
```

SMOKE SENSOR:

```
int smokeD0 = A5;
int greenLed = 11;
int redLed = 12;
// Your threshold value
int sensorThres = 300;

void setup() {
  pinMode(smokeD0, INPUT);
  pinMode(greenLed, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(redLed, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(greenLed, LOW);
  digitalWrite(redLed, LOW);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  int analogSensor = analogRead(smokeD0);
  Serial.println(analogSensor);


  // Checks if it has reached the threshold value
  if (analogSensor < sensorThres)
  {
    Serial.println(" - Smoke");
    digitalWrite(redLed, LOW);
    digitalWrite(greenLed, HIGH);
  }
  else
  {
    Serial.println(" - No Smoke");
    digitalWrite(redLed, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(greenLed, LOW);
  }
  delay(100);
}
```

I want to combine those codes as one with only two outputs:

- the `greenLED` and;
- the `redLED`.

Comment: What is your problem with combining them? You haven't asked an actual question

Comment: The only issue are the same names for `sensorValue`, `thresholdValue` and same pins for red and green led and analog pin A0. All in the first two snippets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Variable renaming

1. Rename `thresholdValue` in the first two sketches to `rainSensorThreshold`, and `lightSensorThreshold` respectively, and `sensorThres` to `smokeSensorThreshold` in the third sketch.
2. Rename `sensorValue` in the first two sketches to `rainSensorValue`, and `lightSensorValue` respectively, and `analogSensor` to `smokeSensorValue` in the third sketch.

#### Change the Analog pin

Use `A1` (or some other analog input other than `A0` or `A5`) for `ldrPin` in the second sketch, for example:

```
int ldrPin = A0;
```

#### Consistant LED pins

Use the same pins in the third sketch, as are used in the first two sketches, for the two LEDs *and* note the change in case:

```
int greenLed = 11;
int redLed = 12;
```

to

```
int greenLED = 6;
int redLED = 7;
```

#### Recompile each sketch

To check that the each sketch still works, recompile each one separately.

#### Combine the code

Finally... Splice the code together appropriately, keeping the three parts separate:

- Global variables
- `setup()`
- `loop()`

Comment: I've got a problem with this --- int sensorValue = analogRead(rainPin);

Comment: Ah, I missed that. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Don't forget to upvote :-)