# How to convert this sketch to keep only one if-else statement?

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors, c++

```
int ldrPin = A0;
int rainPin = A1;
int smokePin = A2;
int greenLED = 6;
int redLED = 7;


// you can adjust the threshold value
int thresholdValue = 500;
int LightSensorThreshold = 500;
int RainSensorThreshold = 500;

void setup() {
  pinMode(ldrPin, INPUT);
  pinMode(greenLED, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(redLED, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(greenLED, LOW);
  digitalWrite(redLED, LOW);
  Serial.begin(9600);

  pinMode(rainPin, INPUT);
  pinMode(greenLED, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(redLED, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(greenLED, LOW);
  digitalWrite(redLED, LOW);
  Serial.begin(9600);

  pinMode(smokePin, INPUT);
  pinMode(greenLED, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(redLED, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(greenLED, LOW);
  digitalWrite(redLED, LOW);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  int lightSensorValue = analogRead(ldrPin);
  Serial.print(lightSensorValue);

  if(lightSensorValue < LightSensorThreshold){
    Serial.println(" - light");
    digitalWrite(greenLED, LOW);
    digitalWrite(redLED, HIGH);
  }
  else {
    Serial.println(" - dark");
    digitalWrite(greenLED, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(redLED, LOW);
  }
  delay(500);

  int rainSensorValue = analogRead(rainPin);
  Serial.print(rainSensorValue);

  if(rainSensorValue < RainSensorThreshold){
    Serial.println(" - It's wet");
    digitalWrite(greenLED, LOW);
    digitalWrite(redLED, HIGH);
  }
  else {
    Serial.println(" - It's dry");
    digitalWrite(greenLED, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(redLED, LOW);
  }
  delay(500);

  int smokeSensorValue = analogRead(smokePin);
  Serial.print(smokeSensorValue);

  if (smokeSensorValue < thresholdValue) {
    Serial.println(" - Smoke");
    digitalWrite(redLED, LOW);
    digitalWrite(greenLED, HIGH);
  }
  else
  {
    Serial.println(" - No Smoke");
    digitalWrite(redLED, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(greenLED, LOW);
  }
  delay(100);



}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sure:

Change these int's to byte, none have values more than 255:

```
int ldrPin = A0;
int rainPin = A1;
int smokePin = A2;
int greenLED = 6;
int redLED = 7;
```

Take these out of setup(), analog input pins don't need this:

```
pinMode(ldrPin, INPUT);
pinMode(rainPin, INPUT);
pinMode(smokePin, INPUT);
```

Take out the duplicates of these lines, pinMode() and turning them off (if LOW is off) only needs to be called once for each

```
pinMode(greenLED, OUTPUT);
pinMode(redLED, OUTPUT);
digitalWrite(greenLED, LOW);
digitalWrite(redLED, LOW);
```

Get rid of two the Serial.begin(9600) lines, calling it once is enough.

Within loop(), get rid of the int's. Those variables were already globally declared, you don't need to re-declare them as type int.

Comment: how to edit those if else statement as one.

Answer (score 2):

First find the duplicated code.

E.g. the fragment

```
  int lightSensorValue = analogRead(ldrPin);
  Serial.print(lightSensorValue);

  if(lightSensorValue < LightSensorThreshold){
    Serial.println(" - light");
    digitalWrite(greenLED, LOW);
    digitalWrite(redLED, HIGH);
  }
  else {
    Serial.println(" - dark");
    digitalWrite(greenLED, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(redLED, LOW);
  }
  delay(500);
```

is repeated three times.

Then find *within* the duplicate code fragments, the differences, which are:

- the pin number
- the value to check against.
- the two texts

Then make a new function containing one duplicated code fragment, and replace the differences, by variables which you pass in the function as arguments:

```
void checkSensor(int pin, int sensorLimitValue, char* okText, char* warningText)
{
  int sensorValue = analogRead(pin);
  Serial.print(sensorValue);

  if(sensorValue < sensorLimitValue) {
    Serial.println(okText);
    digitalWrite(greenLED, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(redLED, LOW);
  }
  else {
    Serial.println(warningText);
    digitalWrite(greenLED, LOW);
    digitalWrite(redLED, HIGH);
  }
  delay(500);
}
```

And call respectively:

```
checkSensor(ldrPin       , LightSensorThreshold, " - light"   , " - dark");
checkSensor(rainSensorPin, RainSensorThreshold , " - it's wet", " - it's dry");
checkSensor(smokePin     , thresholdValue      , " - Smoke"   , " - No Smoke");
```

I switched the green/red values, because I assume when the value is lower than the limit, the green LED should be on, and otherwise the red LED.

Btw, why not use `smokeSensorThreshold` instead of `thresholdValue` to keep it consistent with the other duplicated code fragments?

Comment: I've got a problem with those sketches. The greenLED is turned on and when those sensor sense something it will just turn to redLED. The sketch output is those LED is alternating. Can you help me edit my skectch?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean exactly, but I now see the Red light is on when the sensor value is too high, maybe you want to switch green and red, I will do it in my answer

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: I'd suggested the `smokeSensorThreshold` [yesterday](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/57137/can-you-help-me-combining-these-sensor-sketches-as-one-in-arduino/57138#57138), not sure why OP hasn't used it...